# How to submit data with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a multiple `table.sortables` with a number of links in each one. Using jQuery I have done the following.

1. Modified each row to add a table cell with a span.grab in it.
2. Implemented jQuery sortable on the tables.
3. When a row is dropped. A link appears asking whether the user would like to save.
4. When the user clicks the link I catch it in preparation to send an ajax request to a php script.

This is where I am stuck.

Each tr has the link id on it..

```
<tr id="link1"> ..</tr>
```

Each table has its own id as well.

```
<table class="sortable" id="group1">
```

The question is.. how to pull this data from the html so in my PHP script I preferably get something like this.

```
$_POST['link_order']['group1'] = '1|2|3';
$_POST['link_order']['group2'] = '4|5|6';
```

Any variation of the above is fine, I can also modify the HTML. I just need to send PHP the menus.

I started with this.

```
$('table.sortable').each(function() {

});
```

This is where I got stuck as I didn't know whether the data should go into an object or a string or what. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [serialize()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize) method of the sortable widget. According to the documentation:

> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format
>   'setname_number', and it spits out a hash like
>   "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".
>
> You can also give in a option hash as second argument to custom define
>   how the function works. The possible options are: 'key' (replaces
>   `part1[]` with whatever you want), 'attribute' (test another attribute
>   than 'id') and 'expression' (use your own regexp).

So, if you add an underscore character to your `id` attributes (`link_1` instead of `link1`), `serialize()` will generate a `$POST['link']` parameter by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [serialize](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize) and [toArray](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-toArray) methods for the sortable.

Serialize will give you `foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2`

toArray will give you an array of the items that you can then convert in to your own url parms.